How to do item-wise concatenation of dictionaries
Suppose I have two dictionaries with the same structure (unknown a-priori):
dict1 = {"num": {"a": 1, "b": 2}, "fruit": "banana"}
dict2 = {"num": {"a": 3, "b": 4}, "fruit": "apple"}

How can I merge a list of such dictionaries into a single dict like
merged_dict = {"num": {"a": [1, 3], "b": [2, 4]}, "fruit": ["banana", "apple"]}


Do the input dictionaries every contain lists as values (like the merged_dict) or only single values? And if they do contain lists, should those be treated as elements to be added to lists just like the single values, or should they be merged with other list type elements? And what if "num" is a dict in one dictionary, but a single value in another - can we assume the structure of all the dictionaries in the 'list' is identical?

What is your rule for the depth at which merging happens? What have you tried? We're happy to help fix a [MCVE], but asking us to write code for you to a spec based on a single example is unreasonable.

@ShadowRanger I see. I was following the way this question was asked... As for now, I do not have a code working for the general dictionary structure, should I still put a piece of code that work for the specific dictionary structure that I presented in the example?

You don't provide a lot of context, so assumptions have to be made:

you mention a list, so there may be more than 2 dictionaries
you provide two identically structured dictionaries, so we may assume that is a rule for all dictionaries

Under those assumptions, the solution is quite straightforward:
dict1 = {"num": {"a": 1, "b": 2}, "fruit": "banana"}
dict2 = {"num": {"a": 3, "b": 4}, "fruit": "apple"}


def merge_dicts(ds: list[dict]) -> dict:
    return {
        k: (
            merge_dicts([d[k] for d in ds]) if isinstance(v, dict)
            else [d[k] for d in ds]
        ) for k, v in ds[0].items()
    }


merged_dict = merge_dicts([dict1, dict2])
print(merged_dict)

Note: for k, v in ds[0].items() only loops over the items of the first dictionary in the list, since the assumption is that all dictionaries are structured the same (when it comes to dictionary values vs. other types) and have the same keys.
Output:
{'num': {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4]}, 'fruit': ['banana', 'apple']}


Thanks! This does what I have in mind. I will be more specific next time.
